# Forcing Rich Text by default for iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile-mail

The company I work for uses an Exchange 2010 server, and we have a fair number of users that have iPads/iPhones as secondary devices.  We use a custom signature rule on the exchange server to sign each outgoing email that is not a reply (first-sent emails).  Unfortunately, the iDevices seem to only send in plaintext.  Is there some way to force them to always send as rich text, or alternatively, some sort of cheap/free alternative app that would do this?  Currently, we are unable to implement the signatures for the whole company (only IT has them at the moment) because they will look like trash coming from iDevices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been solved.

There seems no native way of doing this on iDevices, for some very strange reason.

But, since they'll automatically encode in rich text if there are any HTML tags placed in the message by the device itself, putting a single space (&nbsp) in the signature via the mail app itself, and then bold/italic-izing said space makes it work.

Comment: That's correct! Had the same problem. Talked to the company selling us iPhone6 devices. He confirms that adding a simple HTML code (e.g. bold text) to your signature will (en)force HTML and use the custom signatures of the Exchange server.